# How to redirect subfolder as proxy in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, uberspace

I have isso app running on `localhost:63837` and I'd like to proxy requests from `https://www.domain.com/isso`

These were my approaches:

```
RewriteRule https://www.domain.com/isso/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:63837/$1 [P] 
RewriteRule /isso/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:63837/$1 [P] 
RewriteRule /isso(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:63837/$1 [P]
```

Normally I'd adjust `httpd-vhost.conf` but in this case I can't do that on my hoster (uberspace).

```
<Location "/isso">
  ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:63837"
  ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:63837"
</Location>
```

Also, I don't like to use a subdomain for this.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^isso/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:63837/$1 [P]` ?

Comment: @DusanBajic: also 404, unfortunately. But thanks.

Comment: Just to doublecheck, your hoster will not let you edit .conf but it allows you to launch your app there, on port 63837?

Comment: @DusanBajic: Yeah, it's a special shared hosted centos server which can be accessed via cli with no admin rights. There are some scripts helping users opening ports etc. but no vhost.

Comment: @DusanBajic: on localhost your solution works perfect. If you'd like you can provide the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second approach was almost correct (in fact, exactly that would work in `.conf` file).

In per-directory context (`Directory` or `.htaccess`), the *Pattern* is matched against only a partial path: the directory path where the rule is defined is stripped from the path before comparison - up to and including a trailing slash!.
The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which **never** has a leading slash.

Therefore:

```
RewriteRule ^isso/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:63837/$1 [P]
```

Comment: This is perfect and works on my hoster as well now after I got rid of a flaw in my .htaccess. I can't upvote because of my reputation at the moment. +1